# Animation at the beginning of activity skips frames

Tags: android, android-layout, animation, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I am animating a view in an activity after `onGlobalLayoutFinished` is called on the view. My animation is skipping ~300 ms worth of frames in the beginning. If I delay the animation by more than ~300ms, it does not skip any frames. What is going on in the activity that is causing this to happen? How can I stop it or how can I listen for when it is finished?

I have created a dead simple app to demonstrate this behavior.

**contents of `<application>` in AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".main.TestLagActivity"
    android:label="Test Lag Activity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**TestLagActivity.java:**

```
public class TestLagActivity extends ActionBarActivity { 
  private View mRedSquareView;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_lag);

    mRedSquareView = findViewById(R.id.activity_test_lag_redSquareView);

    if (mRedSquareView.getViewTreeObserver() != null) {
      mRedSquareView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
          mRedSquareView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
          animate();
        }
      });
    }
  }

  private void animate() {
    ObjectAnimator xAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mRedSquareView, "x", 0, 1000);
    xAnimator.setDuration(1000);
    xAnimator.start();
  }
}
```

**activity_test_lag.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <View
      android:id="@+id/activity_test_lag_redSquareView"
      android:layout_width="50dp"
      android:layout_height="50dp"
      android:background="#FF0000"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

In this demo, a red square moves from left to right 1000 pixels over 1000 milliseconds. If no delay is set, it skips roughly the first 300 pixels. If a delay is set, it animates smoothly. Please see videos below.

**No delay (skips frames):**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dEwvllhvvN0

**400ms delay (does not skip fames):**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zW0akPhl_9I&feature=youtu.be

Any comments are welcome.

Comment: You really need to show your onPause and onSaveInstanceState methods and potentially your view hierarchy. You may have custom logic blocking in onPause before onSaveInstanceState or you may have a custom view that block in onSaveInstanceState.

Comment: "onPause and onSaveInstanceState normally happen within 20ms of each other in MainActivity" ... what are you doing different in CreatActivity?

Comment: @dcow I should have mentioned the methods are empty, besides the log statements.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman I was referring to the difference when starting a new activity and just turning off the screen.

Comment: @clocksmith you only addressed one third of my comment.

Comment: @dcow I was investigating. The problem has nothing to do with the previous activity. The question is what internal process is blocking the animation? I have made a single activity app that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I have the feeling that the `onGlobalLayout()` callback is being invoked earlier than you need it. Try starting your animation from a `Runnable` that you post to one your your `View`s in `onCreate()` instead.

Comment: @DavidWasser thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and ran it a few times. `onGlobalLayout()` actually gets called about 10ms after the runnable runs that I post to the view, so the result is the same.

Comment: @clocksmith thanks for the vids btw. It makes the issue abundantly clear (:

Comment: @dcow Nothing unusual in the logs. My guess is that SOMETHING is happening in the activity for about 300ms after the views are laid out, but I have no idea what. I just want to be able to listen for when that thing is done so I can animate with skipping frames and without guessing how long that something takes.

Comment: Hey, I'm having the exact same problem. Have you managed to fix it?

Comment: I'm having this exact same problem as well. Any chance you've found a solution since?

Comment: @asaini007 unfortunately, I did not. For other reasons, the UI was changed and this was no longer an issue.

Comment: @clocksmith No problem. I finally found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37958418/animation-at-the-beginning-of-activity-jumps#comment63702750_38099337

Answer (score 2):

This happens because of the activity's transition animation, which is played while the activity is being created. As a result, your custom animation starts while the system is busy drawing the transition.

I haven't found a clean solution yet. For now, I'm simply waiting for the duration of the transition before starting my animation, but it is far from being perfect:

```
// The duration of the animation was found here:
// http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.5_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/anim/activity_open_enter.xml 
new Handler().postDelayed(runnable, android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
```

You could also disable activity transitions instead, with:

```
overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
```

I'm still looking for a way to listen to the exact end time of the transition. Will keep you posted if I ever find a solution.